# does rostopic echo consider as a subscriber?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-comm, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so i been browsing some packages (specially this one. https://github.com/ros-industrial/keyence_experimental).
In this package, they say that 'no pulling from sensor if there is no subscriber'

actual readme contents was "By default the node publishes XYZ point clouds on the profiles topic. Note that nothing will be published if no one subscribes that topic."

And i was kind a lazy to make subscriber so i thought why just try to use rostopic echo as subscriber.
and the question is that, "does the rostopic echo works as a subscriber or other method?"
i wonder how the echo works, and i went to ros_comm github but it was little difficult to find "rostopic echo" part of code.

if there is anyone had same question like me plz inlight me thx!
(excues my bad english)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368217/does-rostopic-echo-consider-as-a-subscriber?/) by [benthebear93](https://answers.ros.org/users/44968/benthebear93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> does the rostopic echo works as a subscriber

yes.

> does rostopic echo [count] as a subscriber?

yes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3